# PHP - Check row exist on a while loop

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I need to check if record exist on a table on a while loop. If it does not, I want to show a message. From the code that I did, it will also output the message if row exist. Below are the codes,

```
<?php 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_dev");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    die();
}

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE staff_id=?")) 
{
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* store result */
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($t_id, $name, $ic_no);

    /* fetch value */
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="nama[]" id="nama" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Nama" value="<?php echo $name?>" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="ic_no[]" id="ic_no" class="form-control"  
            placeholder="No. K/P" value="<?php echo $ic_no; ?>" >
        </div>

    <?php }

    if ($row < 1) {
        echo "No records!";
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();

}
```

What is the proper way to check the condition?

Comment: Use `num_rows`.

Comment: This seems straight-forward enough. But I wouldn't want to say off the top of my head. I'd go look somewhere like this: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/ajax-and-php-building-modern-web-applications-2nd-edition

Comment: How do you want to check if the record exists in the while loop? I guess the question is, what do you want to compare it against to determine whether it exists in the database or not?

Comment: @RaviGehlot Without the while loop, it works if I did `if(!$row)`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried using `num_rows` like you suggest and it work. Just want to know if that is the best practice to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you need to ask, is "what is `$row`?"

Let's step through your code, assuming that everything above the `while` is correct (I don't know, I don't use mysqli):

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

as long as `$stmt->fetch()` returns a value, in this case most likely an object, `$row` receives the object, the `whle` considers this true, and execution will go to the next line.  When `$stmt->fetch()` runs out of rows, it returns `false` and the `while` loop exits.

Meanwhile, while you're in the loop, you access the data from the database, typically by referencing something like `$row->columnName`

so your while loop would be something like this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print "I'm column one: " . $row->columnOnesName . "<br>";
    print "I'm column two: " . $row->columnTwosName . "<br>";
}
```

when you run out of rows, then `$row` gets the value that `$stmt->fetch()` gives it, which most likely is `null`.  This evaluates to not true, and the while loop breaks.

if you then do

```
if ($row < 1) {
```

then it will follow the branch if `null` < 1.

A quick and easy way to see if there were any rows of data is to simply use a flag.

```
$isEmpty = true;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

  $isEmpty = false;

  // display table's output with $row->columnNames
}

if($isEmpty) {
   print "no rows in table";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.